# Use of a counter within a TemplateBeginRepeat loop

Tags: 2009, dwt

In the following block of code:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="slotMiddle" -->
<uc:SlotLoader runat="server">@@Component.ID@@</uc:SlotLoader>
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

I need to use a counter in order to inject a `<div></div>` after **every 3 components** iterated.

> More or less i expect something like this :

```
<uc:SlotLoader runat="server">@@Component.ID@@</uc:SlotLoader>
<uc:SlotLoader runat="server">@@Component.ID@@</uc:SlotLoader>
<uc:SlotLoader runat="server">@@Component.ID@@</uc:SlotLoader>
<div></div>
<uc:SlotLoader runat="server">@@Component.ID@@</uc:SlotLoader>
<uc:SlotLoader runat="server">@@Component.ID@@</uc:SlotLoader>
<uc:SlotLoader runat="server">@@Component.ID@@</uc:SlotLoader>
<div></div>
<uc:SlotLoader runat="server">@@Component.ID@@</uc:SlotLoader>
<uc:SlotLoader runat="server">@@Component.ID@@</uc:SlotLoader>
<uc:SlotLoader runat="server">@@Component.ID@@</uc:SlotLoader>
<div></div>
```

Is this possible to achieve ?

**PS:** Is it also possible to use two different counters ? 
If i for example need to inject something else **every 2 components** iterated.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rahul mentions, I think you're after the TemplateRepeatIndex. Just to elaborate on how it can be used, I recommend using a TemplateBeginIf with a condition:

```
 <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="slotMiddle" -->
    <uc:SlotLoader runat="server">@@Component.ID@@</uc:SlotLoader>    
    <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="(TemplateRepeatIndex % 3) == 0" -->
        <div></div>
    <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
 <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

With this option you don't need a second counter, you could use the same TemplateBeginIf statement with cond="(TemplateRepeatIndex % 2) == 0" to do something every 2 iterations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for TemplateRepeatIndex we use it as:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="MyDummyArray" -->
      @@${TemplateRepeatIndex}@@
      //put your check here on TemplateRepeatIndex
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

[for more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947607/what-can-we-loop-over-in-dwt-layout-template-building-blocks)